# In C++, how to pause and resume a thread from outside?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to pause and resume a thread from outside, and at any time (not at certain breakpoints, and thus `wait` and `notify` won't work).

For example, we create a thread in `foo()`, and then it keeps running. (the `Thread` could be any thread class similar to `std::thread`)

```
void A::foo() {
    this->th = Thread([]{
        // This thread runs a time-consuming job with many steps
        // I hope to pause and resume it at any time outside ths thread (e.g. press a button)
    });
}
```

I need to pause and resume the thread outside the thread, maybe by calling methods like this...

```
void A::bar() {
    this->th->pause();
    cout << "The thread is paused now" << endl;
}

void A::baz() {
    this->th->resume();
    cout << "The thread is resumed now" << endl;
}
```

How can I implement this in C++?

Comment: There is no portable way to do that, definitely not with `std::thread`. This can be done with pthread and signals though. That being said it is infinitely easier (and portable) to periodically check a condition variable in the time-consuming thread.

Comment: Agree with @freakish, this is exactly what `std::conditon_variable`s are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@freakish said it can be done with pthread and signals, but no portable way.

In Windows, I just found `SuspendThread(t.native_handle())` and `ResumeThread(t.native_handle())` (where `t` is of type `std::thread`) are available. These would solve my problem.